# LCD 16x2 failed to display Hello world using NodeMCU1.0

Tags: arduino, nodemcu

I am doing a small project to display text on LCD using NodeMCU1.0. The problem is that the text is not displayed when I upload the sketch "Blank screen only"?
Any help?

```
    #include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

// Set the LCD address to 0x27 for a 16 chars and 2 line display
// Arduino UNO => PIN 4 = SCL, PIN 5 = SDA
// NodeMCU Dev Kit => D1 = SCL, D2 = SDA
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 20, 4);

void setup()
{
    // initialize the LCD
    lcd.begin();
    // Turn on the blacklight and print a message.
    lcd.backlight();
    lcd.print("Hello World");
}
void loop(){
}
```

Comment: Please add some more information on what happens. Do other sketches work? Can you flash an LED? Does an error appear?

Answer (score 0):

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 20, 4);

change to...

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2); //for 16x2 lcd.
then compile and upload ur code, it may be helpful for u.